# How to use logging to input logs of different levels to different files in flask

Tags: python, flask, logging

```
class LogWrapper(metaclass=Singleton):
def __new__(self, log_file, file_output=True, standard_output=False, error_output=True, debug_output=True):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    formater = logging.Formatter(
        '[%(levelname)s] [%(asctime)s] [pid:%(process)s] [%(pathname)s line:%(lineno)s] %(message)s')
    # If you do not use either standard output or log file output, select standard output
    if not file_output and not standard_output:
        standard_output = True
    if standard_output:
        standard_out = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        standard_out.setFormatter(formater)
        self.logger.addHandler(standard_out)

    if file_output:
        log_file = create_log_dirs(log_file) # create log file dir, /log/info/info.log.YYYY-MM-DD
        file_out = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(log_file, encoding='utf-8')
        file_out = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=log_file, when='H', backupCount=24 * 7, encoding='utf-8')
        file_out.setFormatter(formater)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_out)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    if error_output:
        log_file = 'log/error/error.log' # create log file dir, /log/error/error.log.YYYY-MM-DD
        log_file = create_log_dirs(log_file)
        error_out = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(log_file, encoding='utf-8')
        error_out = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=log_file, when='H', backupCount=24 * 7, encoding='utf-8')
        error_out.setFormatter(formater)
        error_out.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        self.logger.addHandler(error_out)

    if debug_output:
        log_file = 'log/debuge/debuge.log'
        log_file = create_log_dirs(log_file)
        debug_out = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(log_file, encoding='utf-8')
        debug_out = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=log_file, when='H', backupCount=24 * 7,
                                                      encoding='utf-8')
        debug_out.setFormatter(formater)
        debug_out.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.addHandler(debug_out)

    self.wlock = Lock()
    return self.logger

def info(self, message):
    self.wlock.acquire()
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    self.logger.info(message)
    self.wlock.release()

def debug(self, message):
    self.wlock.acquire()
    self.logger.debug(message)
    self.wlock.release()

def warning(self, message):
    self.wlock.acquire()
    self.logger.warning(message)
    self.wlock.release()

def error(self, message):
    self.wlock.acquire()
    self.logger.error(message)
    self.wlock.release()
```

logger = LogWrapper('log/info/info.log')

However, in the actual use process, it is found that logs of different info and error levels are written to info.log. None of the debug level logs are recorded, and the debug log records the error level logs. The error.info log file records the error level logs
In addition, the info  debug  warning  error written by myself has not been called